# MBP restarting twice after going into deep sleep from a fully drained battery

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, battery

Ever since I installed Mavericks on my 15" Mid-2012 MBP (4GB), I've noticed that if I let my machine completely drain to 0% and it (supposedly) goes into Deep Sleep, when I plug it back in and restart, I hear the optical drive initialize twice, then I see the Apple logo and the loading wheel, which then takes me to the login screen (I have autologin setup) with the default Mavericks wallpaper then switches to my own wallpaper. After I log back in, I find that whatever apps that I was running before it shut down started back up, while I was on the login screen.

I've checked Console and I notice these entries entered around the same time for when it shuts off.

```
12/17/2013 6:09:20.587 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100027 destroyed
12/17/2013 6:11:04.025 PM WindowServer[100]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "(PID 717)" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0x15a0b, PID 717)
12/17/2013 6:11:04.025 PM WindowServer[100]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "Transmission" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0x15603, PID 710)
12/17/2013 6:11:04.025 PM WindowServer[100]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "Skype" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0x14e07, PID 707)
12/17/2013 6:11:04.025 PM WindowServer[100]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "Textual" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0x1480b, PID 703)
12/17/2013 6:11:04.026 PM WindowServer[100]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "(PID 544)" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0x6053, PID 544)
12/17/2013 6:11:04.026 PM WindowServer[100]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "loginwindow" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0x9303, PID 42)
12/17/2013 6:11:04.027 PM WindowServer[100]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x7fcb7315b840(2001)
12/17/2013 6:11:04.065 PM WindowServer[100]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x7fcb7315b840(2001)
12/17/2013 6:11:05.609 PM WindowServer[100]: _CGXSetWindowBackgroundBlurRadius: Invalid window 0xffffffff
12/17/2013 6:11:05.611 PM loginwindow[42]: find_shared_window: WID -1
12/17/2013 6:11:05.611 PM loginwindow[42]: CGSGetWindowTags: Invalid window 0xffffffff
12/17/2013 6:11:05.611 PM loginwindow[42]: find_shared_window: WID -1
12/17/2013 6:11:05.611 PM loginwindow[42]: CGSSetWindowTags: Invalid window 0xffffffff
12/17/2013 6:11:05.000 PM kernel[0]: Network delay is not specified! Defaulting to 0x384
12/17/2013 6:11:06.000 PM kernel[0]: Network delay is not specified! Defaulting to 0x384
12/17/2013 6:11:24.000 PM kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
12/17/2013 6:22:31.000 PM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1387318951 0
12/17/2013 6:23:34.000 PM syslogd[21]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

(And then about 16 similar ASL Module messages.)

I've done an SMC reset previously but that didn't work.

Should I back up my machine and reinstall OS X from recovery? Or is there something that I can do right now to fix it without reinstalling?

Comment: Is there a reason to restart your MBP? If it is plugged into a power adapter, once it has enough power, it should automatically come back out of Deep Sleep. Instead of the Apple Logo/Wheel, there should be a set of vertical bars lighting up as it comes out of sleep. There are some settings in System Preferences under *Energy Saver* which should also be looked at.

Comment: I would assume (as per my previous experience with laptops since 2007) that if a macbook were to be automatically shut down and go into deep sleep (or rather, hibernate) due to the battery getting to 0%, that it would not turn itself back on, making me press the power button to start it up again. Before Mavericks, the loading bar would come up and load my previous session. Now, that loading seems to fail.

Comment: It depends on how long the power button is *held* down. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5869. 10.7.5 behaves by automatically coming out of sleep when it has enough charge or the power button is *briefly* pressed and a power source is connected without needing to restart the laptop.

Comment: I just tap it after I plug it in and wait for the status light on the magsafe cable to turn from green to orange, just like I've always done with Mountain Lion. It seems like there's an error with how the sleep file is written when dealing with 0% battery. I've already done HDD (mechanical) checks, and nothing's wrong.

Comment: An update: I let my battery run down to 0% and start the process of saving the sleep file. While it was doing so (the indicator light is on but dimmed), I plugged it into a power source. After it finished, I pressed the power button to restart, and lo and behold, it properly resumed. I guess that for some reason the power fully cuts out before it can save state completely.

Comment: Mavericks on 13-in MBP 2012. Battery was completely drained and laptop in deep sleep. Checked LEDs for power, the first one closest to the button blinks. Left it unplugged overnight, plugged in the morning and *briefly* touched power button and normal resumption (vertical bars of resumption, not a reboot) occurred.